# Where's org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert available?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/Assert
```

Seems the runtime.jar has no org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert in it:

[image]

Am I using a wrong version though it's shipped with my eclipse?

**UPDATE**

I don't have Plugin Development Perspective:

[image]

Comment: You have probably not downloaded Eclipse RCP.  You probably have downloaded Eclipse for Java developers.  You can download the RCP plugins from the update manager.

Answer (score 3):

It's in **org.eclipse.equinox.common**.

To check out which JAR a class belongs to you can use "Open Type" dialog - just press Ctrl+Shift+T in Plugin Development Perspective and type the class name.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the `Ctrl+Shift+T` tip. The input line for the name pattern in that dialog has many useful features. You can use `*` and `?` for filtering, or use CamelCase filtering, so entering `IArE` will present (possibly among others) the `IllegalArgumentException`. You can enter abbreviated package names like `j.u.BS` to get (among others) the `java.util.BitSet`.

Comment: Why I don't have Plugin Development Perspective?

Comment: Now it's reporting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/commands/common/EventManager`

Comment: It works in Java perspective too. Plugin devel. perspective is available in Eclipse for RCP and RAP developers as Andrew noted.